# Creating a directory for a vocabulary term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

## Background:

I've opened a new vocabulary named "bc" (an acronym for "Blog categories).

## The problem:

Anytime I go to the webpage of each term of this vocabulary, the url is `sitename.com/term`. INSTEAD OF `sitename.com/bc/term`

This is because when I first built the site, I disabled the option (somehow, it was a long time ago) to create folders for vocabularies.

**What I need** is to add a folder only to that vocabulary, i.e a way to make terms of this vocabulary to appear under sitename.com/bc/term.

How can this be achieved?

**Note**: I've already tried to give a pattern, like `bc`, `[bc]`, `[bc]/`. None of these helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that you have the module [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) enabled. It allows you to create path aliases for mach of your site stuff like nodes and taxonomies. Go to Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases > Patterns. That's where you enter the alias patterns for content, taxonomies, etc.   Set the default alias to `[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]`

It should be mentioned for any case that the default Drupal path for taxonomy terms is `taxonomy/term/[term:id]`

Comment: I approved the edit, but now I don't think this is correct. The default path for taxonomies is `taxonomy/term/[term:id]`.  Please clarify if this is what you meant and I'll re-edit

Comment: I see you fixed my mistake there, it's great, thanks!